# Unwanted Change of Input in Func c#

Tags: c#, linq, class, casting, func

i don't know how to debug the problem so maybe it's a commong beginner error?
 The IEnumerable im using my Where & Select on has a Property 'Amount' in the DocumentPositionMetaDataItem-Property.
While running the code you can see below it always changes it's Value (Amount) to whatever 'AmountToConvert' is.

```
public class OrderPositionItem : IDocumentPositionItem
{
    public int DocumentId { get; set; }
    public string PositionId { get; set; }
    public ArticleItem Article { get; set; }
    public CategoryItem Category { get; set; }
    public UnitItem Unit { get; set; }
    public ValueAddedTaxPositionItem ValueAddedTaxPosition { get; set; }
    public FinancialAccountingAccountItem FinancialAccountingAccount { get; set; }
    public CostCenterItem CostCenter { get; set; }
    public DocumentPositionMetaDataItem DocumentPositionMetaDataItem { get; set; }
    public decimal AmountBilled { get; set; }
    public bool IsAlreadyBilled { get; set; }
    public decimal AmountToConvert { get; set; }
```

The Value thats changing is in the MetaDataItem Property.

```
      public int DocumentsDataNumber { get; set; }
    public string PositionID { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
    public decimal PriceNoVat { get; set; }
    public decimal AddedVat { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public decimal Total { get; set; }


    public decimal TotalWithVat { get; set; }
```

"Amount" is changing to whatever the "Amount To Convert" value in "OrderPositionItem" is. And I dont know why.

This is my List (Queryable) orderPositions, all the Properties 'Amount' on the orderPositions change to whatever 'AmountToConvert' is.

```
 List<OrderPositionItem> orderPositions
```

This is my Code, it converts OrderPositions where Convertible to DeliveryNotePositions.

```
     // assign selected order position items to the delivery note
            // (orderPosition has prop AmountToConvert, only convert this much and only if > 0)
            deliveryNote.DocumentPositionItems = 
                orderPositions.Any() 
                    ? orderPositions
                    .Where(OrderPositionItem.IsConvertibleToDeliveryNotePositionItemFunc)
                    .Select(OrderPositionItem.ToDeliveryNotePositionItemFunc)
                    .ToList()
                    : null;
```

Where Func: IsConvertibleToDeliveryNotePositionItemFunc

```
   public static readonly Func<OrderPositionItem, bool> IsConvertibleToDeliveryNotePositionItemFunc =
        orderPosition => !orderPosition.IsAlreadyBilled &&
                         orderPosition.AmountToConvert > 0 &&
                         orderPosition.AmountToConvert <=
                         orderPosition.DocumentPositionMetaDataItem.Amount - orderPosition.AmountBilled;/* left over amount */
```

Select Func:

```
    public static readonly Func<OrderPositionItem, DeliveryNotePositionItem> ToDeliveryNotePositionItemFunc =
        orderPosition => (DeliveryNotePositionItem) orderPosition;
```

The Cast in the Select Func:

```
        public static explicit operator DeliveryNotePositionItem(OrderPositionItem orderPosition)
    {
        if (orderPosition == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(orderPosition));

        var deliveryNotePositionItem = new DeliveryNotePositionItem()
        {
            // meta data
            DocumentPositionMetaDataItem = orderPosition.DocumentPositionMetaDataItem,
            // article
            Article = orderPosition.Article,
            // category
            Category = orderPosition.Category,
            // unit
            Unit = orderPosition.Unit,
            // value added tax position
            ValueAddedTaxPosition = orderPosition.ValueAddedTaxPosition,
            // cost center
            CostCenter = orderPosition.CostCenter,
            // financial accounting account
            FinancialAccountingAccount = orderPosition.FinancialAccountingAccount,
        };

        // adjust amounts and totals to given order position
        deliveryNotePositionItem.DocumentPositionMetaDataItem.Total =
            deliveryNotePositionItem.DocumentPositionMetaDataItem.Total /
            deliveryNotePositionItem.DocumentPositionMetaDataItem.Amount * orderPosition.AmountToConvert;
        deliveryNotePositionItem.DocumentPositionMetaDataItem.TotalWithVat =
            deliveryNotePositionItem.DocumentPositionMetaDataItem.TotalWithVat /
            deliveryNotePositionItem.DocumentPositionMetaDataItem.Amount * orderPosition.AmountToConvert;
        deliveryNotePositionItem.DocumentPositionMetaDataItem.Amount = orderPosition.AmountToConvert;
        return deliveryNotePositionItem;

    }
```

Value before running the code provided:

[Property Amount & AmountToConvert before Handling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LrLjr.pn)

[Amount after Handling, now is AmountToConvert before handling?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JhOpa.png)

Comment: Debugging the problem is easy: just set the breakpoint in the setter of the offending property.

Comment: Funcs don't randomly change properties. Are you sure the problem isn't in your source data? Use the debugger to inspect the variables in your list _before_ they go into your code.

Comment: Okay thanks i'll try that, i didn't even know you could put a breakpoint there.

Comment: @CodeCaster excactly thats what was going trough my mind. I checked that already tho. The variables change when running this:     deliveryNote.DocumentPositionItems = 
                orderPositions.Any() 
                    ? orderPositions
                    .Where(OrderPositionItem.IsConvertibleToDeliveryNotePositionItemFunc)
                    .Select(OrderPositionItem.ToDeliveryNotePositionItemFunc)
                    .ToList()
                    : null;

Comment: I debugged, nor the getter or setter of the property "Amount" in Class DocumentPositionItem get accessed, the value of it is changed tho!

Comment: This line: `deliveryNotePositionItem.DocumentPositionMetaDataItem.Amount = orderPosition.AmountToConvert` seems to set `Amount` to `AmountToConvert` which I believe is what you are saying is the undesired behaviour... Am I missing something?

Comment: I didn't see your update, but yes thats exactly whats happening.
Im creating a new object, why is there a reference to orderPosition?

            `var deliveryNotePositionItem = new DeliveryNotePositionItem()
            {
                // meta data
                DocumentPositionMetaDataItem = orderPosition.DocumentPositionMetaDataItem,
                // article
                Article = orderPosition.Article,
                // category
                Category = orderPosition.Category,
                // unit
                Unit = orderPosition.Unit};`

Comment: Why the line: `deliveryNote.DocumentPositionItems = orderPositions.Any() ? orderPositions.Where(...) ... ToList() : null`? Wouldn't you rather have an empty collection of DocumentPositionItems if there are no orderPositions?  `deliveryNote.DocumentPositionItems = orderPositions.Where... ToList(),`

Comment: Thats true @HaraldCoppoolse, thank you. I removed the ternary. Either way, my logic throws an error if the list is null or empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing that seems to be causing confusion is this line when creating your new `DeliveryNotePositionItem`:

```
DocumentPositionMetaDataItem = orderPosition.DocumentPositionMetaDataItem
```

This is setting the property to be the same `DocumentPositionMetaDataItem` object as is on your `orderPosition`. It won't create a copy for you or anything else. It means that both objects are now sharing the same `DocumentPositionMetaDataItem`.

This obviously means that when you change it that change is reflected in both places you are looking at. What you need to do is create a new `DocumentPositionMetaDataItem` object somehow based on the original one.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I didn't realize i need to recreate the Objects in my new Object aswell!

Answer (score 0):

Excuse me, what about this line

```
deliveryNotePositionItem.DocumentPositionMetaDataItem.Amount = orderPosition.AmountToConvert;
```

a the end of

```
DeliveryNotePositionItem(OrderPositionItem orderPosition)
```

?

Comment: Yes, correct, it was this line. DocumentPositionMetaDataItem was used by both deliveryNotePositionItem and orderPosition, so when changing Amount on one, the other used the new Amount too.